# Unless I declare my array as a new array with the same contents, the array changes itself in my while loop

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, stack

[What I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZlRx.png)

So I am trying to get the possible flips in an array whilst also using a stack.

For example:

{3, 2, 1, 4} would give me the possible flips [ {2, 3, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, **{4, 1, 3, 2}** ]

{3, 6, 1, 7} would give me the possible flips [ {6, 3, 1, 7}, {1, 6, 3, 7}, **{7, 1, 6, 3}** ]

I've got a separate loop that gets me the reversal (in bold) so that isn't an issue.

The issue at hand currently is that when I am getting the other possible flips, my while loop changes the contents of my test array with the contents of my temp array (hopefully the code snippet highlights this). I have tried to make a copy of the test array but it then changes the contents of that too.
The code below works, but as you can imagine, I want to be able to enter my own numbers and have it work etc etc etc

```
  public static void flipForSuccessors() {
        int[] test = {3, 2, 1, 4};
      int thePurplePointer = 1;

      System.out.println("Test is " + Arrays.toString(test));
      System.out.println("==================");

      int[] tempList = test;
      Stack<Integer> flipStack = new Stack<>();
 while(thePurplePointer < test.length - 1) {
     test = new int[]{3, 2, 1, 4}; // Whenever I remove this from the while loop, it doesn't work anymore
    tempList = test;
    for(int i = 0; i < test.length - thePurplePointer; i++) {
        flipStack.add(test[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < tempList.length-thePurplePointer; i++) {
        tempList[i] = flipStack.pop();
    }
    System.out.println("Temp is " + Arrays.toString(tempList));
   thePurplePointer++;
}

      for(int i = 0; i < tempList.length / 2; i++) { // This all works
          int tempInt = tempList[i];
          tempList[i] = tempList[tempList.length - i - 1];
          tempList[tempList.length - i - 1] = tempInt;
      }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempList));

      System.out.println("==================");

    }
```

I'm probably being very stupid. If anybody figures out a solution, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by flips?  Are you talking about permutations or just swaps of adjacent items.

Comment: @WJS I've edited the post to try and show you a visual representation of what I'm trying to do. Similar to permutations, but a little different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tempList = test

copies the reference to the array, not the array, so both tempList and test refer to the same array. To make a copy of the array use

> tempList=test.clone();

Comment: Jonathan, I would not have been able to carry on with my project without you. You're a top man!